# How to replace a word in a specific line where the replace pattern contains a variable?

Tags: shell, sed, replace

I have the following files:

```
[root@f9044b5d9d1e aws-marketing-and-sales]# grep -HRe ".*\/common\/.*\${local.parent_folder_name}" *
ap-northeast-1/config/config/terragrunt.hcl:  inline_policy = templatefile("${get_parent_terragrunt_dir()}/common/${local.environment}/config/${local.parent_folder_name}/inline-policy-s3.tpl", {
ap-northeast-2/config/config/terragrunt.hcl:  inline_policy = templatefile("${get_parent_terragrunt_dir()}/common/${local.environment}/config/${local.parent_folder_name}/inline-policy-s3.tpl", {
ap-south-1/config/config/terragrunt.hcl:  inline_policy = templatefile("${get_parent_terragrunt_dir()}/common/${local.environment}/config/${local.parent_folder_name}/inline-policy-s3.tpl", {
ap-southeast-1/config/config/terragrunt.hcl:  inline_policy = templatefile("${get_parent_terragrunt_dir()}/common/${local.environment}/config/${local.parent_folder_name}/inline-policy-s3.tpl", {
```

I'm trying to replace the occurrences of "${local.parent_folder_name}" where the line contains "common" in all files with the parent folder name, like this:

```
for file in $(grep -HRe ".*\/common\/.*\${local.parent_folder_name}" *); do
  filename=$(echo $file | cut -d: -f1)
  parent=$(echo $file | rev | cut -d/ -f2 | rev)
  sed -i "/common/\${local.parent_folder_name}/$parent/g" $filename
done
```

This is the error that I get when running the above script:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unknown command: `$'
```

I've found some SO questions regarding this but none of them have examples with using a variable as the replace pattern.

I've also tried different separators (| , !) but to no avail.

Edit:
@moshe, it didn't work, that's the output:

```
grep -Re "/common\/.*\${local.parent_folder_name}" . | while read -r grep_line; do
  if [[ $grep_line == *"$0"* ]]; then
    continue
  fi
  echo $grep_line
  filename=$(echo $grep_line | cut -d: -f1)
  parent=$(echo $grep_line | rev | cut -d/ -f2 | rev)
  echo "parent: $parent"
  sed -i "/common/s?\${local.parent_folder_name}?$parent?g" $filename
done
./ca-central-1/config/config/terragrunt.hcl:  inline_policy = templatefile("${get_parent_terragrunt_dir()}/common/${local.environment}/config/${local.parent_folder_name}/inline-policy-s3.tpl", {
parent: ${local.parent_folder_name}
sed: 1: "./ca-central-1/config/c ...": invalid command code .
./us-west-2/config/config/terragrunt.hcl:  inline_policy = templatefile("${get_parent_terragrunt_dir()}/common/${local.environment}/config/${local.parent_folder_name}/inline-policy-s3.tpl", {
```

I tried replacing the "." to "8" in the first grep and it worked only on some of the files but not on all. Any idea?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure what the `parent` var should be, probably should fix it, but the script could look like that

```bash
#!/bin/bash
grep -re "/common\/.*\${local.parent_folder_name}" . | while read -r grep_line; do
  if [[ $grep_line == *"$0"* ]]; then
    continue
  fi
  echo $grep_line
  filename=$(echo $grep_line | cut -d: -f1)
  parent=$(echo $grep_line | rev | cut -d/ -f2 | rev)
  echo "parent: $parent"
  sed -i "/common/s?\${local.parent_folder_name}?$parent?g" $filename
done
```

Note that `sed` takes a pattern (`/common/`) and then a command (`a` to append, `d` to delete, `s` to replace)

We want to change only lines with the pattern `/common/` in them,
so after the pattern, we perform a regular search and replace - `s/\${local.parent_folder_name}/$parent/g`

To make it more readable, I changed the separator `/` to `?`

So the `sed` is:

```bash
sed -i "/common/s?\${local.parent_folder_name}?$parent?g" $filename
```